# I want to change attribute value of a class using CSS

Tags: html, css, attributes

I want to change attribute value of a class using CSS. For Example:
html code is:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" title="My Account"> My Account </a>
```

Say that I need to change href to be `href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/"` or maybe i want to change title to be `title="Go To Your Account"`

I want do this using CSS. I used this CSS code to change title attribute but it hides the element itself

```
    a[title="My Account"]{
          visibility:hidden;
    }
    a[title="My Account"]:before{
          content: "Go To Your Account|";
    }
```

Comment: You cant do that in CSS, its easy in JS

Comment: Agreed. CSS is purely declarative. You set it - and then it just stays that way. What is your reason for this? Maybe we can suggest a better way - if we understand that.

Comment: @sheriffderek I just don't know how to edit on JS code, as I am using WordPress Platform for my website and it is not a native website. If you can tell me how to edit on JS code, that will be fine with me.

Comment: WordPress is really just PHP (which creates HTML) - so, if you want to add some JavaScript, you can do that in script tags - or in a .js file that you reference in the footer etc. You can learn more about it on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using javascript.. You can also use jquery library to write less and code more

```html
<a id="my_acc" href="#acc" title="My Account"> My Account </a>


<script>
var my_acc = document.getElementById("my_acc");
my_acc.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.setAttribute("title", "Go to your Account");
});
</script>
```

N: You need to add javascript at the end of your body tag in html for using event listeners

Comment: How can I add javascript at the end of your body tag in html?

Comment: just add the javascripts at the end of your body tag!