# How to Add attributes to all Elements of a specific type without using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, element

I want to add the following attributes to all svg element in the page:

```
aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

1. If adding them manually, it will bloat the whole page and is time-consuming.
2. If using JavaScript, it will delay the page loading speed.
3. It seems that CSS also cannot do this task, see [I want to change attribute value of a class using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606221/i-want-to-change-attribute-value-of-a-class-using-css)

Are there any other choices?

Comment: I guess you can only do it using js. Also it will not take too long to make the changes. You would have to compromise it for loading speed. Another way is that you can find all elements in an ide and add attr manually at all places at once.

Comment: Will really adding them manually bloat the page? Seems like the best way will be `Ctrl+F`'ing `<svg` to `<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

Comment: This seems like [premature optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).  The idiomatic thing to do here would be to add these attributes directly into the markup, unless you are imbuing behavior that will be broken for users with JS disabled.  The only reason this would appreciatively slow your page load would be if you had hundreds or thousands of SVG loading, in which case you probably want to re-evaluate if some sort of lazy-loaded approach would be more appropriate.  In my opinion, and without more context, you are most likely over-thinking this.